# Slowness of multiprocessing.dummy.Pool's join/terminate method

Tags: python, multithreading

While using the `join` (or `terminate`) method of the `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` class, the call takes about 100 miliseconds, which seems to be slow to me. This example:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import time

def foo():
    pass

pool = Pool(1)
pool.apply_async(foo)
pool.close()
start_time = time.time()
pool.join()
print("%f" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

displays a number that is always greater than 0.100 (seconds) whatever the version of python is used (I tried with 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7).
I get the same result when I use `terminate` instead of `join`.

When I use `cProfile` to understand where the time is spent, I have this (I stripped all non-relevant entries):

```
18698 function calls (18434 primitive calls) in 0.125 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  25/1    0.000    0.000    0.125    0.125 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.125    0.125 test_pool.py:1(<module>)
    22    0.101    0.005    0.101    0.005 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.100    0.100 pool.py:576(join)
     4    0.000    0.000    0.100    0.025 threading.py:1000(join)
     4    0.000    0.000    0.100    0.025 threading.py:1038(_wait_for_tstate_lock)
[...]
```

I understand from this that `Pool.join()` calls `Thread.join()` on 4 threads (I guess from reading code that is corresponds to `_worker_handler`, `_task_handler`, `_result_handler` of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class plus the number of requested threads in the pool), but I still can't figure out why `Thread.join()` takes a fixed 0.025 seconds duration to execute. It seems to be related to lock acquisition..

Please note that until Python 3.7.1, the `terminate()` function was not called automatically at garbage collection contrary to what was documented. Since Python 3.7.1 (https://bugs.python.org/issue34172), `terminate()` is "really" called at garbage collection, meaning this slowness appears even if `terminate()` or `join()` have not been called explicitely.

Does anybody would have an explanation of this slowness and possibly a way to avoid it ?

In the context of the program I'm writing such a slow-down is not visible, but in unit testing where creating and terminating a pool is done hundreds of times, this makes test execution much, much slower.

Comment: what's your operating system?

Comment: @martineau good catch.

Comment: Nicolas: You're aware Python is (usually) an interpreted language, right?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @martineau: yes I do; so I guess you consider that 100ms is expected ? For instance, doing the same test with a Thread.join() takes about 0.000010 seconds, that's why I wonder why in the context of a Pool.join() the operation takes so much time.

Comment: Nicolas: I would assume it's due to the overhead `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` introduces while replicating the regular `multiprocessing` API—a fairly common aspect of such "wrappers". For the dirty details, you could peek at its [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/dummy).

Comment: @martineau: I'm not sure because 1: `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` is simply a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` and this one mostly inherit from `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` and 2: I see from cProfile stats that the time is spent in `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` own methods and `Thread.join()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I get the same result on Mac, meaning it seems to be not operating-system related.